# Reproject MODIS data using R (results in NAs or no spatial extent)

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, rgdal, r-modis

I am using GLASS albedo data stored [here](ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/GLASS/ABD/AVHRR/) for pre-2000 (AVHRR) data and [here](ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/GLASS/ABD/MODIS/0.05D/) for post-2000 data (MODIS).  My end goal is to create a raster stack of each month that contains white sky albedo data from 1982-2015. The problem I have run into is that the MODIS and AVHRR data are in different spatial reference systems and I can't seem to reproject them to be in the same system.

I convert from hdf to tif using R like this:

```
fileavhrr <- ".../GLASS02B05.V04.A1990161.2018062.hdf"
filemodis<-".../GLASS02B06.V04.A2013169.2017128.hdf"
gdal_translate(get_subdatasets(filemodis)[10], dst_dataset =
        ".../modis.tif") 
gdal_translate(get_subdatasets(fileavhrr)[8], projwin = c(-180,90,180,50), dst_dataset = ".../avhrr.tif") #ideally I'd only like data north of 50 degrees

avhrr<- raster(".../avhrr.tif")

#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 800, 7200, 5760000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, 50, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +no_defs 
#values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)

modis<- raster(".../modis.tif")

#class       : RasterLayer   
#dimensions  : 3600, 7200, 25920000  (nrow, ncol, ncell) 
#resolution  : 154.4376, 308.8751  (x, y)  
#extent   : -20015109, -18903159, 8895604, 10007555  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)  
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181
    +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs   
#values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)
```

Here are things I have tried:

1.) Use the [MODIS Reprojection Tool](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool).  For whatever reason, this tool seems to think the subdatasets of the MODIS .hdf files are only one tile (the upper left most tile, tile 0,0) and not the global dataset.  My understanding is that the MODIS data are global (not in tiles?), so I do not know why the MRT is doing this.

2.)   Use the raster package in R.

```
projectedMODIS <- projectRaster(modis,avhrr,method="bilinear")
```

This returns a raster with values that are all NA:

```
class       : RasterLayer  
dimensions  : 800, 7200, 5760000  (nrow,> ncol, ncell) 
resolution  : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y) 
extent      : -180, 180,> 50, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) 
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +no_defs  
values      : NA, NA  (min, max)
```

3.) Use the gdalUtils package in R:

```
gdalwarp(srcfile=get_subdatasets(filemodis)[10], dstfile= ".../gdalMODIS_avhrr.tif", s_srs = crs(modis), t_srs =crs(avhrr) )
```

This returns a raster with essentially no spatial extent.

```
gdalMODISavhrr<-raster(".../gdalMODIS_avhrr.tif")
#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 357, 12850, 4587450  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 0.02801551, 0.02801573  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 179.9993, 79.99838, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +no_defs 
#values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)
```

Any ideas on why reprojecting this MODIS data is so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but from looking at the package `gdalUtils`, the function `gdalwarp()` might do what you need?

Comment: That's what I tried in #3.  It returns a raster with essentially no spatial extent.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that - however, it seems to me that this worked: you wanted to assign it the AVHRR projection, correct? According to your first code block, the CRS for the AVHRR file is `+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +no_defs` (this is NAD27 projection, see page 2 of https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf). And that is also the projection that your last code block shows.

Comment: If you want to use the `raster` package as in #3, you probably have to grab the layer that you want beforehand. There is some explanation here: https://khufkens.com/2016/04/20/modis-hdf-data-extraction-in-r/

Comment: The code `get_subdatasets(filemodis)[10]` gives the layer.

It turns out the metadata for both the AVHRR and MODIS datasets is wrong.  They should be in Geographic CRS.  More on the discussion here: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304304/reproject-modis-data-using-r-results-in-nas-or-no-spatial-extent?noredirect=1#comment491170_304304